# Enable multi user access in silent-flow to be able to use server with different accounts parallel

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

The **[silent-flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/standalone-samples/silent-flow)** example works perfectly. I can login and logout.

But when I try to login in 2 different browsers with 2 different accounts. Then the old browser will be logged in with the last logged-in account when page was reloaded.

[image: grafik]

I know that it always takes the last `homeAccountId` from cache as the code says:

`const account = await msalTokenCache.getAccountByHomeId(app.locals.homeAccountId);`

My question is now, how to enable multi users? How to rewrite the `app.locals`?  Is there any example?

Otherwise is need to create some custom code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try [this sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/silent-flow/index.js#L127).

According to [this doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/accounts.md#notes)，`getAccountByHomeId()` only supports working single account scenario, so here we need a new [sample which uses](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/accounts.md#usage) `getAllAccounts()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure what you mean. Did you find a solution somewhere? Or is it just an info that it's not possible. Your image does not show a solution as it just takes the first account. Currently, I found a solution to get it working with setting a browser cookie of the homeAccountId. That works well but is not the highest security as someone could "simply" steal the cookie.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding sir. I thought you wanna a sample for multiple accounts. And according to the doc I mentioned in above, we could see that it's necessary to add custom code to 'choose a specific account' after getAllAccounts(). Setting cookie may not be a perfect choice but I haven't came up with a better idea. Because we have to send the account information from the browser to server so that backend app could know how to filter all the cached accounts.

Comment: Correct. Ok so you have no idea that is better than my cookie solution. Anyway if you find something more secure let me know. :)